# I have a slight issue with alignment in my CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I've tried several things like making the divs smaller (even very tiny to see if they go next to each other) and experimenting with inline-block/float left and right but I can't get my divs side by side, below is the CSS please help

```
#ContentHome {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 79%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
}
#Side {
    clear: both;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family: "Myriad Pro", Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: How does your html look like?

Comment: <div id="ContentHome"><article> <img src="pllogo.png" alt="Power League Logo" width="187" height="110">
  <h3> The Start Of A New Era </h3>
  <p> CONTENT HERE </p>
  <h3> History Of Success </h3>
  <p> MORE CONTENT
  </p>
  </article>
  
  </div>
  <div id="Side">
           <p align="center"> More Content Here <p>
    <div align="left"><img src="logo.png" width="100%" height="auto"></div>
  </div>

Comment: Your issue has to do with Inline-Block respecting whitespace.  Check my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29651275/2414886

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/rsgammwp/)

See the updated `css` below. What i have done is that, I removed both the `clear:both;` and `display:inline-block;` from your `css` and added `float:left;` to both of the `<div>`s.

**CSS**

```
#ContentHome {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 79%;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
}
#Side {
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 20%;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
}
```

- I've used background color in the fiddle just to show that the two divs are aligning correctly

Answer (score 1):

try removing `clear:both` from the divs you want to go side by side.

Comment: still nothing I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 1):

remove `clear: both` and then give them `float: left;`
http://jsfiddle.net/ydrzcrjp/

Comment: wow so it does, it makes me wonder if there's something in my HTML or maybe container that's making it still one on top of the other

Answer (score 1):

```
#ContentHome {
    float: left;
    width: 79%;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
}
#Side {
    float:left;
    width: 20%;
    font-family:"Myriad Pro", Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: thin solid #FFF;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Why the `clear: both` in both elements? If you need to keep the elements cleared, wrap them and set `clear: both` to the wrapper.